# HTML forms losing all styles on ajax form submit

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have an issue that i cannot seem to get to the bottom of!

I have a series of forms generated via a jQuery plugin that render fine and all is good in the hood, however whenever I submit the form (via a button calling an AJAX function) on success of the AJAX call the form loses all styles and defaults back to browser defaults.

This is really doing my head in as it ruins the who style layout of the site.

Cheers.

Comment: Care you post what you have in a `jsFiddle.net` so we can take a look? Or post the code here?

Comment: What is that this ajax call is giving in the response?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure without more context, but this sounds like a common issue that's caused by the fact that AJAX postback doesn't trigger the code that's styling everything. You can get around this like so:

```
$(function () {
  doThatStyling();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

  function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    doThatStyling();
  }
});
```